# Force excel to tick checkbox

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I am currently making an excel template for tracking employee times. Because they have badge IDs, I am having them scan the ID which initiates a timestamp.

Rather than have them clock both in and out, I have decided to use a checkbox to only clock back in after breaks,lunch etc.

This may be time consuming, and also lead to erroneous check boxes, which is why I would like to find a way for the user to scan their ID again, force a checkbox tick and initiate the timestamp for each additional scan.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I actually dont know how to write VBA, but am going to try your suggestion right now and will report back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveX Controls you can tick a checkbox using something like
(Check Box is called "CheckBox1")

```
With ActiveSheet
    .CheckBox1.Value = True
End With
```

And un-tick it using:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .CheckBox1.Value = False
End With
```

And for form control check boxes you can do the same using:
(Check box here is called "Check Box 1")

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1
End With
```

And to un-tick it

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
End With
```

You can then get this to run when the 'ID' is scanned and put the timestamp in as well